# Message not received

Tags: discussion, support

I check this **[post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88648/how-do-i-fix-a-site-after-i-removed-a-module)**, one of the user tried to message me, but I'm not received that message, I checked my [responses](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=responses&sort=comments&StartDate=2013-10-12%2007:46:06Z), but it is not present there. I think this is because of that user mentioned like this "**@Bala,**" with the comma. I'm sure most of them will add comma at the end and I think this should be fixed with some solution, otherwise most of them will not get message when adding comma at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't get any notification because you are the second user that comment was referring to. Notifications are sent to just two users: the user who is @-referred and the user who wrote the post. It is not possible to notify more than two users.

Commas are ignored when looking for the username. If you were the only referred user, you would get notified with *@Bala,* too.

Comment: why this limitation, only to 2 users.

Comment: Editors of the post are also notified, as if they were authors. And if there are only 2 people in a comment thread, OP and one commenter, commenter is notified as if OP's comments were at him. @Bala limitation is there to prevent forum-like discussion and spam in comments.